# Not a git repository error when updating via Composer

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, composer-php

I'm trying to update my Symfony 2 project from 2.1.4 to 2.1.7 using composer and run `php composer.phar update` as normal, after updating a few dependencies I receive the following error:

```
[RuntimeException]
Failed to clone http://github.com/fabpot/Twig-extensions via git, https
and http protocols, aborting.

- git://github.com/fabpot/Twig-extensions
  fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

- https://github.com/fabpot/Twig-extensions
  fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

- http://github.com/fabpot/Twig-extensions
  fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I've checked the URL and can confirm that it exists, I'm also able to `git clone` it without any issues from the same CLI.

What's odd is if I run `php composer.phar update twig/extensions` separately it seems to update without a problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This typically happens if you have an old symfony copy that shipped with the vendors installed as git repos but with the git repos removed. To fix it you should just remove the vendor directory so they will reinstall from scratch as git clones or as zip archives, but without any previous assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Note that currently, I experience a similar issue while using `composer` with **hhvm** and PHP 7.

```
[RuntimeException]
Failed to execute git checkout 'hash' -- && git reset --hard 'hash' --
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

The error appears depending on the `composer.json` not always but rather regularly. I switch off **hhvm** to get it working.